# Different idle times (screen locking) for local vs. remote logins

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows

Is it possible to have different screensaver locking times for local vs. remote (rdp) logins on Windows? I don't know much about Windows admin, just that this config is pushed through GPO.

Comment: So you're saying that this condition exists currently and you're asking if it's possible in order to confirm your suspicions? Or are you asking if it's possible to do this via GPO because you'd like to set this up?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that we currently have a screensaver policy pushed through GPO, but it applies identically to local and remote logons. This is annoying because when you have rdp sessions open and you go away for 5 minutes, you have to type the damn password not just once but several times.

Answer (score 4):

There's no built-in functionality to do this. If I were going to do it I'd remove any screensaver timeout related settings from Group Policy Administrative Templates and deploy logon a script to manage the setting. That logon script could check the `CLIENTNAME` environment variable for `Console` (because RDP-based logons would have the remote client computer's name here). It could be something as simple as:

```
@echo off

rem Timeout for RDP sessions
set TIMEOUT=600

rem If a console session (non-RDP) set the timeout differently
if "%CLIENTNAME%"=="Console" set TIMEOUT=300

rem Put the timeout value into the registry
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v ScreenSaveTimeOut /d %TIMEOUT% /t REG_SZ /f

rem Call API to re-read parameters from the registry
rundll32 user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```